# Rigidly register a 2D image to a 3D volume with good initial guess for affine transformation

Tags: matlab, image-processing, geometry, transformation, image-registration

I have a 3D volume and a 2D image and an approximate mapping (affine transformation with no skwewing, known scaling, rotation and translation approximately known and need fitting) between the two. Because there is an error in this mapping and I would like to further register the 2D image to the 3D volume. I have not written code for registration purposes before, but because I can't find any programs or code to solve this I would like to try and do this. I believe the standard for registration is to optimize [mutual information](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_information). I think this would also be suitable here, because the intensities are not equal between the two images. So I think I should make a function for the transformation, a function for the mutual information and a function for optimization.

I did find some Matlab code on a mathworks [thread](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/312687) from two years ago, based on an [article](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/17278510). The OP reports that she managed to get the code to work, but I'm not getting how she did that exactly. Also in the IP package for matlab there is an [implementation](http://nl.mathworks.com/help/images/examples/registering-multimodal-3-d-medical-images.html?prodcode=IP), but I dont have that package and there does not seem to be an equivalent for [octave](http://wiki.octave.org/Image_package). [SPM](http://www.fil.ion.ucl.ac.uk/spm/) is a program that uses matlab and has registration [implemented](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s-91ulNhtHc&x-yt-ts=1421914688&x-yt-cl=84503534), but does not cope with 2d to 3d registration. On the file exchange there is a brute force [method](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/4145-automatic-image-registration-using--normalized--mutual-information-for-users-of-ip-toolbox) that registers two 2D images using mutual information.

What she does is pass a multi planar reconstruction function and an similarity/error function into a minimization algorithm. But the details I don't quite understand. Maybe it would be better to start fresh:

```
load mri; volume = squeeze(D);

phi = 3; theta = 2; psi = 5; %some small angles
tx = 1; ty = 1; tz = 1; % some small translation
dx = 0.25, dy = 0.25, dz = 2; %different scales
t = [tx; ty; tz];
r = [phi, theta, psi]; r = r*(pi/180);
dims = size(volume);
p0 = [round(dims(1)/2);round(dims(2)/2);round(dims(3)/2)]; %image center
S = eye(4); S(1,1) = dx; S(2,2) = dy; S(3,3) = dz;

Rx=[1 0 0 0;
    0 cos(r(1)) sin(r(1)) 0;
    0 -sin(r(1)) cos(r(1)) 0;
    0 0 0 1];
Ry=[cos(r(2)) 0 -sin(r(2)) 0;
    0 1 0 0;
    sin(r(2)) 0 cos(r(2)) 0;
    0 0 0 1];
Rz=[cos(r(3)) sin(r(3)) 0 0;
    -sin(r(3)) cos(r(3)) 0 0;
    0 0 1 0;
    0 0 0 1];
R = S*Rz*Ry*Rx;
%make affine matrix to rotate about center of image
T1 = ( eye(3)-R(1:3,1:3) ) * p0(1:3);
T = T1 + t; %add translation
A = R;
A(1:3,4) = T;
Rold2new = A;
Rnew2old = inv(Rold2new);

%the transformation
[xx yy zz] = meshgrid(1:dims(1),1:dims(2),1:1);
coordinates_axes_new = [xx(:)';yy(:)';zz(:)'; ones(size(zz(:)))'];
coordinates_axes_old = Rnew2old*coordinates_axes_new;
Xcoordinates = reshape(coordinates_axes_old(1,:), dims(1), dims(2), dims(3));
Ycoordinates = reshape(coordinates_axes_old(2,:), dims(1), dims(2), dims(3));
Zcoordinates = reshape(coordinates_axes_old(3,:), dims(1), dims(2), dims(3));

%interpolation/reslicing
method = 'cubic'; 
slice= interp3(volume, Xcoordinates, Ycoordinates, Zcoordinates, method);
%so now I have my slice for which I would like to find the correct position

% first guess for A
A0 = eye(4); A0(1:3,4) = T1; A0(1,1) = dx; A0(2,2) = dy; A0(3,3) = dz; 
% this is pretty close to A
% now how would I fit the slice to the volume by changing A0 and examining some similarity measure?
% probably maximize mutual information?
% http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/14888-mutual-information-computation/content//mi/mutualinfo.m
```

Comment: Phew. This sounds like a difficult (but interesting) problem. We can't assume any continuity in the volume data, so a newton iteration will likely fail. One could look for features in the 3D and 2D data similiar to [SIFT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale-invariant_feature_transform) and then do some [RANSAC](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/RANSAC-Algorithmus). If your guess is good enough you could do [ICP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterative_closest_point) on the feature points. Will the affine transformation preserve the lengths (only rotation+translation)? This would simplify a little.

Comment: Yes it is a difficult problem because there are so many local minima. The problem has been solved already in literature but there is no working code poblished. I think the prerequisite is a good first approximation and restricted parameters.

For a volume to volume registration there are ready to use approaches. I believe that in that field mutual information is regarded as the best way to assess alignment so I would like to take that approach here as well.

As for your question: yes only rotation and translation (and scaling but the scaling is known for my problem), no skewing.

Comment: I however don't understand how mutual information would be directly applicable, as the probability spaces are not identical. Could you elaborate?

Comment: I was thinking calculate MI over the 2D image and the transformed 3D image (which then also would be a 2D image in the same resolution, after the transformation). Would those have the same probability spaces (Im not sure what a probability space is)?

Comment: Ok, I get what you mean. It should be applicable this way. I guess maximizing the mutual information is important, when the 2D data isn't exactly an extraction of the 3D data, but may have a different scaling. (As in: The 2D image has different brightness or has more/less contrast than the 3D-slice). Because if the 2D image is really an exact extraction, it would be simpler to minimize the euclidean distance of the 2D data and the slice of the 3D data. (Via: `norm(I_2D(:)-I_3Dslice(:),2)` )

Comment: In reality they have different intensities, I will add that information to the question.

Comment: I've got some code working now. The mutual information definitely improves but the fit does not. Will put some code up here later but I'm also interested to see your idea, it might work better than optimizing MI now that I'm trying that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I was hoping for someone else's approach, that would probably have been better than mine as I have never done any optimization or registration before. So I waited for Knedlsepps bounty to almost finish. But I do have some code thats working now. It will find a local optimum so the initial guess must be good. I wrote some functions myself, took some functions from the file exchange as is and I extensively edited some other functions from the file exchange. Now that I put all the code together to work as an example here, the rotations are off, will try and correct that. Im not sure where the difference in code is between the example and my original code, must have made a typo in replacing some variables and data loading scheme.

What I do is I take the starting affine transformation matrix, decompose it to an orthogonal matrix and an upper triangular matrix. I then assume the orthogonal matrix is my rotation matrix so I calculate the euler angles from that. I directly take the translation from the affine matrix and as stated in the problem I assume I know the scaling matrix and there is no shearing. So then I have all degrees of freedom for the affine transformation, which my optimisation function changes and constructs a new affine matrix from, applies it to the volume and calculates the mutual information. The matlab optimisation function patternsearch then minimises 1-MI/MI_max.

What I noticed when using it on my real data which are multimodal brain images is that it works much better on brain extracted images, so with the skull and tissue outside of the skull removed.

```
%data
load mri; volume = double(squeeze(D));

%transformation parameters
phi = 3; theta = 1; psi = 5; %some small angles
tx = 1; ty = 1; tz = 3; % some small translation
dx = 0.25; dy = 0.25; dz = 2; %different scales
t = [tx; ty; tz];
r = [phi, theta, psi]; r = r*(pi/180);
%image center and size
dims = size(volume);
p0 = [round(dims(1)/2);round(dims(2)/2);round(dims(3)/2)]; 
%slice coordinate ranges
range_x = 1:dims(1)/dx;
range_y = 1:dims(2)/dy;
range_z = 1;

%rotation 
R = dofaffine([0;0;0], r, [1,1,1]);
T1 = ( eye(3)-R(1:3,1:3) ) * p0(1:3); %rotate about p0
%scaling 
S = eye(4); S(1,1) = dx; S(2,2) = dy; S(3,3) = dz;
%translation
T = [[eye(3), T1 + t]; [0 0 0 1]];
%affine 
A = T*R*S;

% first guess for A
r00 = [1,1,1]*pi/180;
R00 = dofaffine([0;0;0], r00, [1 1 1]);
t00 = T1 + t + ( eye(3) - R00(1:3,1:3) ) * p0;
A0 = dofaffine( t00, r00, [dx, dy, dz] );
[ t0, r0, s0 ] = dofaffine( A0 );
x0 = [ t0.', r0, s0 ];

%the transformation
slice = affine3d(volume, A, range_x, range_y, range_z, 'cubic');
guess = affine3d(volume, A0, range_x, range_y, range_z, 'cubic');

%initialisation
Dt = [1; 1; 1]; 
Dr = [2 2 2].*pi/180;
Ds = [0 0 0];
Dx = [Dt', Dr, Ds];
%limits
LB = x0-Dx;
UB = x0+Dx;
%other inputs
ref_levels = length(unique(slice));
Qref = imquantize(slice, ref_levels);
MI_max = MI_GG(Qref, Qref);
%patternsearch options
options = psoptimset('InitialMeshSize',0.03,'MaxIter',20,'TolCon',1e-5,'TolMesh',5e-5,'TolX',1e-6,'PlotFcns',{@psplotbestf,@psplotbestx});

%optimise
[x2, MI_norm_neg, exitflag_len] = patternsearch(@(x) AffRegOptFunc(x, slice, volume, MI_max, x0), x0,[],[],[],[],LB(:),UB(:),options);

%check
p0 = [round(size(volume)/2).'];
R0 = dofaffine([0;0;0], x2(4:6)-x0(4:6), [1 1 1]);
t1 = ( eye(3) - R0(1:3,1:3) ) * p0;
A2 = dofaffine( x2(1:3).'+t1, x2(4:6), x2(7:9) ) ;
fitted = affine3d(volume, A2, range_x, range_y, range_z, 'cubic');
overlay1 = imfuse(slice, guess);
overlay2 = imfuse(slice, fitted);
figure(101); 
ax(1) = subplot(1,2,1); imshow(overlay1, []); title('pre-reg')
ax(2) = subplot(1,2,2); imshow(overlay2, []); title('post-reg');
linkaxes(ax);

function normed_score = AffRegOptFunc( x, ref_im, reg_im, MI_max, x0 )
    t = x(1:3).';
    r = x(4:6);
    s = x(7:9);

    rangx = 1:size(ref_im,1);
    rangy = 1:size(ref_im,2);
    rangz = 1:size(ref_im,3);

    ref_levels =  length(unique(ref_im));
    reg_levels =  length(unique(reg_im));

    t0 = x0(1:3).';
    r0 = x0(4:6);
    s0 = x0(7:9);
    p0 = [round(size(reg_im)/2).'];
    R = dofaffine([0;0;0], r-r0, [1 1 1]);
    t1 = ( eye(3) - R(1:3,1:3) ) * p0;
    t = t + t1;
    Ap = dofaffine( t, r, s );

    reg_im_t = affine3d(reg_im, A, rangx, rangy, rangz, 'cubic');

    Qref = imquantize(ref_im, ref_levels);
    Qreg = imquantize(reg_im_t, reg_levels);

    MI = MI_GG(Qref, Qreg);

    normed_score = 1-MI/MI_max;
end

function [ varargout ] = dofaffine( varargin )
% [ t, r, s ] = dofaffine( A )
% [ A ] = dofaffine( t, r, s )
if nargin == 1
    %affine to degrees of freedom (no shear)
    A = varargin{1};

    [T, R, S] = decompaffine(A);
    r = GetEulerAngles(R(1:3,1:3));
    s = [S(1,1), S(2,2), S(3,3)];
    t = T(1:3,4);

    varargout{1} = t;
    varargout{2} = r;
    varargout{3} = s;
elseif nargin == 3
    %degrees of freedom to affine (no shear)
    t = varargin{1};
    r = varargin{2};
    s = varargin{3};

    R = GetEulerAngles(r); R(4,4) = 1;
    S(1,1) = s(1); S(2,2) = s(2); S(3,3) = s(3); S(4,4) = 1;
    T = eye(4); T(1,4) = t(1); T(2,4) = t(2); T(3,4) = t(3);
    A = T*R*S;

    varargout{1} = A;
else
    error('incorrect number of input arguments');
end
end

function [ T, R, S ] = decompaffine( A )
    %I assume A = T * R * S
    T = eye(4);
    R = eye(4);
    S = eye(4);
    %decompose in orthogonal matrix q and upper triangular matrix r
    %I assume q is a rotation matrix and r is a scale and shear matrix
    %matlab 2014 can force real solution
    [q r] = qr(A(1:3,1:3));
    R(1:3,1:3) = q;
    S(1:3,1:3) = r;

    % A*S^-1*R^-1 = T*R*S*S^-1*R^-1 = T*R*I*R^-1 = T*R*R^-1 = T*I = T
    T = A*inv(S)*inv(R);
    t = T(1:3,4);
    T = [eye(4) + [[0 0 0;0 0 0;0 0 0;0 0 0],[t;0]]];
end

function [varargout]= GetEulerAngles(R)

assert(length(R)==3)

dims = size(R);

    if min(dims)==1
        rx = R(1); ry = R(2); rz = R(3);
        R = [[                           cos(ry)*cos(rz),                          -cos(ry)*sin(rz),          sin(ry)];...
             [ cos(rx)*sin(rz) + cos(rz)*sin(rx)*sin(ry), cos(rx)*cos(rz) - sin(rx)*sin(ry)*sin(rz), -cos(ry)*sin(rx)];...
             [ sin(rx)*sin(rz) - cos(rx)*cos(rz)*sin(ry), cos(rz)*sin(rx) + cos(rx)*sin(ry)*sin(rz),  cos(rx)*cos(ry)]];
        varargout{1} = R;
    else
        ry=asin(R(1,3));
        rz=acos(R(1,1)/cos(ry));
        rx=acos(R(3,3)/cos(ry));

        if nargout > 1 && nargout < 4
            varargout{1} = rx;
            varargout{2} = ry;
            varargout{3} = rz;
        elseif nargout == 1
            varargout{1} = [rx ry rz];
        else
            error('wrong number of output arguments');
        end
    end
end
```